# Google Drive API V3 Download returns 416 Error

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a bin subfolder in Google drive that has 1500-1600 bin files, and amounts to around 1 GB in storage.
My program stops downloading at 544 files, and I don't know why.
Here are my limits in Google API console:

- Quota Name    Limit
- Queries per day   1,000,000,000
- Queries per 100 seconds per user  1,000
- Queries per 100 seconds   10,000

Here is the method to compile the list of bin files.

```
public static final List<File> getbinfolderlist(Drive service, String bin_folder_id) throws IOException {
        try {
            List<File> list = new ArrayList<File>();
            String pageToken = null;
            do {
                FileList result = service.files().list()
                    .setQ("'" + bin_folder_id + "' in parents")
                    .setPageToken(pageToken)
                    .execute();
                    for (File file : result.getFiles()) {
                        list.add(file);
                    }
                    pageToken = result.getNextPageToken();
                } while (pageToken != null);
                return list;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Running this in main method:

```
List<File> bin_files = getbinfolderlist(service, bin_folder_id);
System.out.println(bin_files.size());
```

returns the exact number of files in the bin folder, so I know that that all the bin files are listed.

The method to iterate through the list and download bin files is as follows:

```
public static void downloadBinFiles(Drive service, List<File> bin_files, String dst_dir) {
        try {
            int i = 0;
            for (File file : files) {
                String fileId = file.getId();
                String fileName = file.getName();
                //need to check if folder exists. If not, create folder.
                System.out.println("File downloading is: " + fileName);
                OutputStream outputstream = new FileOutputStream(dst_dir + fileName);
                    service.files().get(fileId)
                        .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputstream);
                    outputstream.flush();
                    outputstream.close();
                i++;
                System.out.println(i + " files downloaded.");
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console console = System.console();
            console.writer().println("Error.");
        }
    }
```

And for some reason it always gets "Error" at file 544.
Is there some quota I'm hitting that I don't know about and need to increase? 
Is there something in the code?
I'm using this command to execute the download of the bin files in main method

```
downloadBinFiles(service, bin_files, bin_path );
```

Error message I get is this:

```
com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 416 Requested range not satisfiable
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "requestedRangeNotSatisfiable",
    "message": "Request range not satisfiable"
   }
  ],
  "code": 416,
  "message": "Request range not satisfiable"
 }
}

        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1070)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.executeCurrentRequest(MediaHttpDownloader.java:245)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpDownloader.download(MediaHttpDownloader.java:199)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:562)
        at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Get.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(Drive.java:3256)
        at DriveQuickstart.downloadBinFiles(DriveQuickstart.java:223)
        at DriveQuickstart.main(DriveQuickstart.java:127)
```

Edit: In case this is relevant, the sizes of the bin files range anywhere from < 0 KB to just under 14,000 KB. Folder size is 843 MB.

Comment: What is the error code and message from the exception? That might be more helpful than just printing "Error."

Comment: @Cheticamp edited post to include error messages

Comment: That is an HTTP 416 error code (HttpResponseException)  and not specifically related to Drive. I would look at file number 544 and see if there is anything amiss with it. You can search for the code to see what trouble others have had and what solutions they found. This does not look like a limits issue.

Comment: @Cheticamp some of the files are zero-byte files. How can I keep the program running so that if it encounters a zero-byte file, it just skips it and continues onto the next file?

Comment: You could try moving the try..catch block within the loop. I find it hard to believe that Drive can't handle a zero-length file. I would check into that first - maybe find out how to check the length before download is attempted.

Comment: This error looks related to the file #544 itself. To prevent errors due to that file, could you take it off the folder and repeat the operation?